# Using C# Docker api to query docker engine from inside container

Tags: c#, docker, docker-for-windows

I've just started to look at Docker as a way of moving our legacy C++ server app into a container (so we can run multiple isolated servers on the same physical machine). This has all gone fine (on my Windows 10 machine), I'm able to prepare an image and run the container and it all works. So, I then thought it would be handy to be able to have a little REST api inside a container so outside clients could find out information about the running servers/containers. I've found a c# api

https://github.com/microsoft/Docker.DotNet

which works locally with code like this

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.ScriptTimeout = 300;
        DockerClient client = new DockerClientConfiguration(new Uri("npipe://./pipe/docker_engine")).CreateClient();

        IList<ContainerListResponse> containers = await client.Containers.ListContainersAsync(
            new ContainersListParameters()
            {
                Limit = 10,
            });
```

So, I went into vs2017 to create a webapi project, turned on docker support and moved the snippet of code into a controller so I could see if I could view the hosts running container. Unfortunately the command just gives a timeout error. I'm assuming I have to do something to get access to the host docker engine. So, I tried adding this to the docker-compose.yml file

```
version: '3.4'

services:
    serverinfoapp:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}serverinfoapp
    volumes:
        - source: '\\.\pipe\docker_engine'
          target: '\\.\pipe\docker_engine'
          type: npipe
    build:
      context: .\ServerInfoApp
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

but it still doesn't work.

I am a complete beginner with Docker so any help would be appreciated.

regards

Comment: what are the errors you get ?

Comment: I just get a System.TimeoutException: 'The operation has timed out.' when executing the client.Containers.ListContainersAsync line. I've tried adding a timespan into the client config ctor but that doesn't help.

Comment: It's more common to pass in all external information via environment variables, rather than have a pod reach "out" to its controller. E.g., you can use some kind of templating system for your deployment definitions that can pass the image version (or whatever) to the pod.

Comment: Thanks Stephen. I did get it working in the end by using .net core. I'm just playing around with architecture ideas at the moment

Answer (score 1):

Tried in vs2019 using a .net core version and it seems to work

UPDATE

After doing some more work into this I thought I'd post a bit more info in case anyone found it helpful. Basically I wanted something similar to Portainer (https://www.portainer.io/) which is to have a web app running inside a container that allows me to control other docker containers (running my legacy app). I can't just use Portainer as there's additional app-specific functionality I needed to add. So, the key to start with is, if you're going to use a server OS, and you want to use named pipes, make sure you use Server 2019.

As this blog explains, server 2019 allows you to use named pipes to access the Docker API

https://blog.sixeyed.com/what-you-can-do-with-docker-in-windows-server-2019-that-you-couldnt-do-in-windows-server-2016/

Also, if you're using docker-compose, make sure you add the appropriate volumes in and also specify running as a user that has appropriate rights

For example

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  yourservice:
    image: <dockerimage>
    container_name: yourcontainer
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:80
      - ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection=blahblah
      - HOST_IP=blahblah
    volumes:
        - source: '\\.\pipe\docker_engine'
          target: '\\.\pipe\docker_engine'
          type: npipe
    ports:
      - "7000:80"
    user:
        ContainerAdministrator
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: pathtodockerfile
```